# Django matches url with double slash, but not without

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following urls.py:

```
# ...imports...

urlpatterns = [
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls,),
    url('', include('main.urls', namespace="main")),
]
```

`main.urls` looks like this:

```
# ...imports...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^confirmation_email$', views.email_confirmation_sent, name="confirmation_email"),
    url(r'^oauth_callback$', views.oauth_callback, name="oauth_callback"),
    url(r'^.*', views.index, name='index')
]
```

I would expect /oauth_callback to be routed to views.auth_callback, but it doesn't work. On the other hand, //oauth_callback is routed there. It seems like the initial slashes that are implicitly matched are taken into account twice.

On the other hand, `social.apps.django_app.urls', looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # authentication / association
    url(r'^login/(?P<backend>[^/]+){0}$'.format(extra), views.auth,
        name='begin'),
    url(r'^complete/(?P<backend>[^/]+){0}$'.format(extra), views.complete,
        name='complete'),
    # disconnection
    url(r'^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+){0}$'.format(extra), views.disconnect,
        name='disconnect'),
    url(r'^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/(?P<association_id>[^/]+){0}$'
        .format(extra), views.disconnect, name='disconnect_individual'),
]
```

It is included in my main urls.py file the exact same way I included my `main.urls` file, but going to `/login/twitter` works correctly. Apart from some formatting differences, and some logic to handle trailing slashes (the `.format` call at the end of the patterns), I don't see anything that could cause this difference in behavior. What could be causing trouble here?

---

#### edit

If I manually set up an urlresolver, and resolve the path `/oauth_callback`, it works correctly.

```
>>> from django.core import urlresolvers
>>> urlresolvers.get_urlconf()
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.ROOT_URLCONF
'podato.urls'
>>> urlresolvers.set_urlconf(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
>>> urlresolvers.get_urlconf()
'podato.urls'    
>>> resolver = urlresolvers.get_resolver(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
>>> resolver.resolve("/")
ResolverMatch(func=main.views.index, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=index, app_names=[], namespaces=['main'])
>>> resolver.resolve("/oauth_callback")
ResolverMatch(func=main.views.oauth_callback, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=oauth_callback, app_names=[], namespaces=['main'])
```

I've checked that the request.path_info isn't changed. Nore is any middleware changing the urlconf.

Comment: Your url patterns look ok to me, it looks like `/oauth_callback` should resolve to the `views.oauth_callback`. Double check that you are actually running the code that you think you are, and that you have restarted your server after any code changes.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, I manually set up an url resolver in the django shell, and it worked correctly. So either the url resolver is being altered somewhere, or the path_info passed into it is altered.

Comment: Can you print `request.path`, `request.path_info` and `request.META['SCRIPT_NAME']`?

Comment: I'm sorry to anyone interested in the answer to this question, but I just somehow magically fixed the error. I monkeypatched `django.core.handlers.BaseHandler.get_request` to insert some logging, and it suddenly worked. Even after removing the monkeypatch.

Comment: The url pattern for `main` and `social` are both the same - is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, their urls should both be rooted at the base level.